Azure Application Gateway V2, cert error for http only services
I have an Azure Application Gateway V2, my issue / question is why does the gateway choose a cert from another listener when I visit a webpage / service that I have only configured for http when I visit https?
Is there a way to either drop the traffic rather then presenting a cert for a service to which the request was not for?
The cert that's provided looks to be from the lowest priority listener.

To drop the traffic rather than presenting a certificate for a service to which the request was not intended, you can configure the listener for HTTPS to use a different certificate or disable it altogether. This way, when a request is made for HTTP, the listener for HTTP will be used instead and no certificate will be presented. Configure an HTTP listener


Azure Application Gateway V2, cert error for http only services

If theApplication Gateway is using a certificate from another listener when you visit a webpage that you have only configured for HTTP, as this issue occurs because of listener for HTTPS traffic has a higher priority than the listener for HTTP traffic, and the gateway is using the certificate associated with the HTTPS listener.
You can create a listener for HTTP traffic with a lower priority than the listener for HTTPS traffic to drop the traffic instead of presenting a certificate for a service to which the request was not intended in application gateway
By following the above method when a request is made for HTTP traffic, the Application Gateway will use the listener with the higher priority, which is associated with the HTTPS traffic, and the request will be dropped. configure HTTP listener by following the MS Doc

After creating the listener for HTTP traffic, make sure that it has a lower priority than the listener for HTTPS traffic. It will adjust the priority of the listeners in the Listeners section in Application Gateway.
References:

Create an application gateway with HTTP to HTTPS redirection using the Azure portal - Add a listener and redirection rule

